# Geoserver not uploading styled layer descriptor(.sld) files

Tags: gis, qgis, geoserver, sld

I'm currently having trouble uploading styled layer descriptor files onto geoserver.  I have been trying to upload a styled layer however each time I click the upload (even validate or save) button nothing happens.

I have tried with several different files, and I have uninstalled and reinstalled geoserver(I'm using the linux binary: [geoserver-2.21-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip](https://geoserver.org/release/stable/) but the problem remains. I have uploaded the .sld files before so I know it used to work, I just don't understand why it stopped.

I tried uploading a file I got from the geoserver documentation - [sld cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/polygons.html#polygon-with-styled-label), as well as several I created on QGIS.

If anyone has encountered such a problem or knows the solution, I would appreciate some help!
Here's part of the log file:

```
07 Nov 10:55:36 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
07 Nov 10:55:36 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
07 Nov 10:55:36 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
07 Nov 10:55:36 DEBUG  [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
07 Nov 10:55:36 DEBUG  [geoserver.filters] - Compressing output for mimetype: text/html;charset=utf-8
07 Nov 10:55:36 DEBUG  [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
07 Nov 10:55:37 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:55:37 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 464us for /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:55:42 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:55:42 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 432us for /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:55:47 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:55:47 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 437us for /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:55:52 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:55:52 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 430us for /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:55:57 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:55:57 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 231us for /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:56:02 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:56:02 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 423us for /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:56:07 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:56:07 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 465us for /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:56:12 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:56:12 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 504us for /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:56:17 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:56:17 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 534us for /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:56:22 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:56:22 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 456us for /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:56:27 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:56:27 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 448us for /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:56:32 TRACE  [platform.resource] - polling contents of /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
07 Nov 10:56:32 TRACE  [platform.resource] - delta computed in 443us for /usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc-layers
```

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Hey @IanTurton, thanks for responding. I did as you suggested. Quite honestly, I have  no idea what those logs even mean